# SQLite - show specific data on click of ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a tabbed activity in my app. Inside I have 2 fragments/tabs. The 1st is **Cours** and the 2nd is **Notes**.

I'm using sqlite to add everything in the right table.

I have a table **Cours** and a table **Notes**. In **Notes** Ii have a FK which is the id of the table **Cours**.

In the first tab, I have a listView who is already populated. In the 2nd tab I populate another ListView.

That ListView comes from a table. I am able to get the ID of the item I clicked on the first ListView and insert it as FK in that table.

Here's the thing: If I click in Item1 of the first ListView, I only want to show the Notes I added where the FK is equal to the ID of the Item I clicked in the first ListView.Same thing if I click in Item2 of the first listView. So basically, I want to populate my 2nd listView depending on the Item I clicked on the first listView.

But, instead, my listView doesn't show any more and I don't know why.

Here's my code :

SharedPreferences to get the ID

```
   final SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
   long cours = sharedPref.getLong("IdCours",0);
   int id_cours = (int)cours;
```

**Method to getAllNotes (created on the DatabaseHelper)**

```
public List<NotesTextuelles> getAllNotesTextuelles(int idcours) {

    List<NotesTextuelles> NotesTListe = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NOTES+" WHERE "+COLONNE_FKCOURS+"="+idcours+"";
     Open();
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            NotesTextuelles notes = new NotesTextuelles();
            notes.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            notes.setDescription(cursor.getString(1));
            notes.setTitre(cursor.getString(2));
            NotesTListe.add(notes);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return NotesTListe;
}
```

And where I populate the ListView in OngletNotes.java

```
  final ListView listViewNotes = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListNotes);

    DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

    List<NotesTextuelles> listeNotesTextuelles;
    final ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    listeNotesTextuelles = dbhelper.getAllNotesTextuelles(id_cours);

    if (!listeNotesTextuelles.isEmpty())
    {
        String item;
        String[] notes = {""};
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(notes));
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

        listViewNotes.setAdapter(adapter);

        for (int i = 0; i < listeNotesTextuelles.size(); i++)
        {
            item = listeNotesTextuelles.get(i).getTitre();
            arrayList.add(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Collections.sort(arrayList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        }

    }
```

OnItemClickListener

```
      listViewCours.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            SharedPreferences prefs_id = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor_id = prefs_id.edit();
            long itemid= listViewCours.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
            String a = String.valueOf(itemid);
             //toast to check if ID is good
            Toast ok = Toast.makeText(getContext(), a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
             ok.show();

            editor_id.putLong("IdCours",itemid);
            editor_id.commit();
            ((Onglets)getActivity()).goToFragment(1);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Try to use a CursorAdapter in your ListView when you have a database, not a ArrayAdapter

Comment: Thank's for the advice, but how do I do that ?

Comment: Doesn't really matter for the question, but it's a suggestion. You say "doesnt show anymore", so please describe what you changed and how you are debugging your application

Comment: I said that because I was able to see the notes I created, but it didn't matter if I clicked on Item1 or Item2, so the same notes were shown for all the items. Then I changed my query inserting the WHERE condition and it stopped showing

Comment: see the last parameter passed to `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener#onItemClick` method

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean psking..

Comment: you are using `OnItemClickListener` right? so when you click on `ListView`'s item `onItemClick` method gets called - so you can get the second list: `"I only want to show the Notes I added where the FK is equal to the ID of the Item I clicked in the first ListView"`

Comment: Yes yes sure, but I already checked and it passes the ID correctly. I make a Toast and i checked if the ID is good and everything is ok..

But I'm not sure of one thing : you are saying that I have to get the method to get the notes on the first fragment on the OnItemClickListener ?

Comment: post your `onItemClick` method

Comment: i don't think `getItemIdAtPosition()` will get you the ID you want, this will get the item (row) id in the listview, not the database ID (PK) you want to have. and thats why no FK is matched with this ID in the second table, try to Log this value `itemid` in `onItemClick()` and see what you have, actually i think this will give the value already passed to `onItemClick()` which is the last parameter `long l`